# Running a script on startup for all users in a GROUP

Tags: windows-7, windows, script

Trying to solve the problem of running a script for users who profiles do not yet exist (has not logged in yet), ideally if there was a way to assign a script (on startup - like under the START menu) to all users that are part of the specific GROUP that would be good.

Running windows XP, 7, and 10...

Any ideas?

Comment: group policy. https://technet.microsoft.com/de-ch/library/ee431705(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Doesn't support WinXP, also not sure how that can be used to target specific users